# Right query to limit results in search

Tags: php, mysql

My db structure is as follows: **categories** table

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title     | varchar(260) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug      | varchar(260) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| custom    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**category_to_content** table

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content_id  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And **`content`** table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| heading      | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subheading   | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content_text | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see, typical adjacency list model in `categories` table, `category_to_content` is here because some categories share same content...
There are 4 levels currently, and 'level 0' categories are actually big/main categories (infobases in this case), and i want to limit search JUST to (sub)categories/content which belongs to: **current level 0 category** (parent_id of level 0 categories is, well.. 0).

I'm using Codeigniter, query builder class (not mandatory, i can use plain sql query, too, if needed), and returned query looks like this:

```
SELECT `heading`, `slug`
FROM `content`
JOIN `category_to_content` ON `category_to_content`.`content_id` = `content`.`id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id`=`category_to_content`.`category_id`
WHERE `categories`.`id` IN('1,2,3') // current level 0 category //subcategories id's, 12,3, just as example...
AND   (
`content`.`heading` LIKE '%pod%'
OR  `content`.`subheading` LIKE '%pod%'
 )
 LIMIT 10
```

However, this doesn't return desired results in all cases. If i remove parentheses from AND portion of query, i got results, BUT from all main categories. With parentheses, no results, in most cases...

E.g. when search term is 'about' i got proper results, when i try with 'podiatry' - no results.
Sample data:

[image: Categories]
[image: category_to_content]
[image: content]

Just to clarify - IN portion works fine, i got proper level 0 **subcategories** ids on every page.

If you can't see my error (probably something trivial for MySQL gurus), i can send sample data (export from PhPMyAdmin).

EDIT1: Example: When i type 'pod' i would like to get slug from categories table -> 'podiatry', and heading from 'content' table - 'What is podiatry'.
Interesting, when i type 'about' i get desired results (from desired level 0 **SUB**category). DB export - ASAP, so you can test by your self...

EDIT2: link to sample data: http://pastebin.com/YHziZH8f

EDIT3: in this case, i made 3 main/level0 categories (podiatry - cat id=1, infobase2, cat id=208, test3, cat id=213). They all (almost) have some subcategories, and content related to them. If we are on 'podiatry' page - `current level 0 category subcategories should be searched`. I want to limit search just to these subcategories (**current** level 0 subcategories). So, if i am on 'podiatry' page, i need 'about' content just for podiatry category (no 'about' from/for the rest of categories).

EDIT4:

Example of successful query:

```
SELECT `heading`, `slug`
FROM `content`
JOIN `category_to_content` ON `category_to_content`.`content_id` = `content`.`id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id`=`category_to_content`.`category_id`
WHERE `categories`.`id` IN('209,210,211,212')
AND   (
`content`.`heading` LIKE '%about%' 
OR  `content`.`subheading` LIKE '%about%'
 )
 LIMIT 10
```

I got: heading 'About Infobase2', and 'about-infobase2' slug.

Second search term:

```
SELECT `heading`, `slug`
FROM `content`
JOIN `category_to_content` ON `category_to_content`.`content_id` = `content`.`id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id`=`category_to_content`.`category_id`
WHERE `categories`.`id` IN('209,210,211,212')
AND   (
`content`.`heading` LIKE '%categ%' 
OR  `content`.`subheading` LIKE '%categ%'
 )
 LIMIT 10
```

No results. If you test sample data you will see that there is Category 2 (id=210) in categories table, referenced as: category_id 210, content id 48, in category_to_content table, and Category 2 heading in content table (id=48)... What i'm doing wrong... I can't get that data. :(

Comment: Ooh sample data and desired result, please

Comment: I see no level 0 category in `category_to_content` table (at least in what you show here). Can you show relevant data?

Comment: Huh, please give me few minutes. @caCtus, level 0 categories doesn't have content, i will send mysql dump in few minutes and edit question, to show desired results...

Comment: If level 0 categories don't have content, I don't understand this : `i want to limit search JUST to categories/content which belongs to: current level 0 category`. Please be more specific or give examples. No need to dump the whole database, only part of it with an example.

Comment: Also you say `parent_id of level 0 categories is 0` but in your query you have `IN('1,2,3') // current level 0 id's`. parent_id of categories 2 and 3 is not 0. Definition of "level 0 category" is not clear. :)

Comment: @caCtus, call them 'placeholders' - these level 0 categories are just 'holders' for the rest. Hope it is clear...

Comment: Sorry but what "level 0 categories" are and what data you want to get from the query is still not clear.

Comment: E.g. check sample data - should be clear, i hope... I have 3 'infobases' in this case : 'podiatry' , infobase2' and 'test3'...

Comment: So "infobase" is what you earlier called "level 0 category"?

Comment: level 0 = category which' doesn't have parent - it's parent = 0, hence, main category, the rest of categories are just subcategories of these 'main' categories...

Comment: OK but you told that you want content which belongs to level 0 category, when level 0 category have no content.

Comment: Or do you want to search from level 1 categories, and the content attached to level 1 categories? (What I call level 1 = whose parent is level 0)

Comment: Yes, i want content from subcategories of main/level 0 (infobase) whatever... category...that's why IN is there (i got all subcategories id's and place them in query) Sorry for confusion... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: first I join all tables needed

```
SELECT content.heading, categories.slug
FROM content
INNER JOIN category_to_content ctc ON ctc.content_id = content.id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = ctc.category_id
```

Then we need to keep only "level 1 categories" (direct subcategories of level 0 categories): I used a subquery instead of listing needed ids. It's more dynamic that way: if you add new categories, no need to update the query.

```
WHERE categories.parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = 0)
```

Finally, search by keyword.

```
AND (content.heading LIKE '%pod%' OR  content.subheading LIKE '%pod%')
```

(I'm not sure wether you want to add `OR categories.slug LIKE '%pod%'` in that part of your query or not.)

And you can add `LIMIT 10` at the end if needed.

---

A word about what was wrong in your query, it's this line:

```
WHERE `categories`.`id` IN('1,2,3')
```

- it should have been `IN(1,2,3)` or `IN('1','2','3')` (see the quotes)
- "level 1" categories are not only 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Thanks for help, but... i still don't get right results. Btw, i am creating IN portion dynamically (1,2,3) are there just as example, but i will probably use subquery rather than current way i am using... It seems i didn't explained problem well... will try again. :) E.g. if i place 'about' as search term - i got 3 results, i need just one. If i am on 'podiatry' page -> id is '1' - that's current parent category, and all podiatry subcategories id's pulled off from DB)... Tried to change your subquery, to get only one result, i have set parent_id to 1 - no results. With 0, - redundant results.

Comment: If you tried queries on my sample data, you know what i mean, hopefully... :)

Comment: I tried it and it did what I expected, I guess I still don't understand what you are trying to do. :/

Comment: Omg... i need quotes,that's it. Thanks!

Comment: It was only the `IN` clause? (Sorry I saw this issue in your query only after a while, otherwise I would have told you from the beginning. :o )

Comment: Yes, lol... I knew it is something trivial, and you pointed it correctly, but... i should go to fishing, now, probably...